# Terminal not displaying normally - "[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected:"

Tags: terminal, path, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I switched to zsh on my mac recently, and I was having trouble making coderunner work on vscode - normal terminal commands such as --uninstall-extension weren't working. So I tried updating the path to the shell using exec /usr/bin/zsh and I got an error like this:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected
```

I tried restarting the terminal, but it still looks like this:

```
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected
drwxrwxr-x  3 alexei  admin   96 14 May 22:37 /usr/local/share/zsh
drwxrwxr-x  4 alexei  admin  128 14 May 22:56 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Then I tried putting ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true as the first line in the .zshrc file, which didn't work. Then tried this:

```
➜  ~ compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w
There are insecure directories:
➜  ~ source .zshrc
➜  ~ chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
➜  ~ open ~/.zshrc
➜  ~ open ~/.zshrc                 
➜  ~ chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
➜  ~ compinit -u
➜  ~
```

And nothing seems to fix it...can anyone help please??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you've done research on other relevant Stack Overflow questions and Github issues before posting, which is a hallmark of a good question. However, the terminal text you quote would be easier to read formatted as code instead of bold. Cleaning that up would make it more likely you'll get an answer.